# Error con Composer al Crear Proyecto Laravel 5.x

Tags: laravel-5, composer

Querida Comunidad,en esta ocasion me encuentro por aca debido a un problema que me surgio al descargar nuevos proyectos de laravel en mi maquina:

La Situacion es la Siguiente:

Al Momento de descargar un nuevo proyecto en laravel desde mi maquina me arroja el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y nose como descargar los proyectos de laravel, estuve indagando por la WEB pero las soluciones que me brinda no me funcionaron.

Espero que por aca alguien tenga algun indicio o sepa como resolver dicho Error.

Comment: ¿Que soluciones intentaste?

Comment: intentaste composer update?

Comment: Gracias por sus Respuestas, si intente Composer Update pero nada :/